# Easily add vertical line to pandas plot.bar() time series data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I was trying to do something simple: plot some bar plots and add a vertical line, for a dataframe like this:

```
  index         data
2021-06-05    14628.0
2021-06-06     1969.0
2021-06-07    50918.0
```

And doing this:

```
 df.data.plot.bar()
 plt.axvline('20210606')
```

To my surprise, this only works on `df[col].plot()` but not on `df[col].plot.bar()`. I tried figuring it out and I found I could manage to plot my line by finding what x data matplotlib's actually getting:

```
ax = plt.gca()
rectangles = ax.patches
plt.axvline((rectangles[1].get_x() + rectangles[1].get_width()/2), color='r')
```

Which brings the desired plot, but in a very non-straightforward way. Is there any way to achieve this by actually using dates or should I get used to `ax.patches` ?

Thanks !

Comment: I had a brainfart with `df.data.plot.bar()`. As shown in the duplicate, you must use the index location of the date value, as `plt.axvline(1, c='red')`

Comment: `plt.axvline(df.index.searchsorted('2021-06-06'), c='red')`